# How to use an array value as field in Java? a1.section[2] = 1;

Tags: java, android

New to Java, and can't figure out what I hope to be a simple thing.

I keep "sections" in an array:

```
//Section.java
public static final String[] TOP = {
    "Top News",
    "http://www.mysite.com/RSS/myfeed.csp",
    "top"
};
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
Article a1 = new Article();
a1.["s_" + section[2]] = 1;  //should resolve to a1.s_top = 1;
```

But it won't let me, as it doesn't know what "section" is.  (I'm sure seasoned Java people will cringe at this attempt... but my searches have come up empty on how to do this)

**Clarification:**

My article mysqlite table has fields for the "section" of the article:

```
s_top
s_sports
...etc
```

When doing my import from an XML file, I'd like to set that field to a `1` if it's in that category.  I could have switch statement:

```
//whatever the Java version of this is
switch(section[2]) {
    case "top": a1.s_top = 1; break;
    case "sports": a1.s_sports = 1; break;
    //...
}
```

But I thought it'd be a lot easier to just write it as a single line:

```
a1["s_"+section[2]] = 1;
```

Comment: Eh?  Could we see the `Article` class?

Comment: Maybe what you want is `Map` (TreeMap/HashMap)?

Comment: Why do you want to achieve this?

Comment: I've added clarification to my question above.  Hopefully that explains better. (Why does the Article class matter?  It has the fields and seem unrelated to my question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, it's a pain to do what you want to do in the way that you're trying to do it.

If you don't want to use the switch/case statement, you could use reflection to pull up the member attribute you're trying to set:

```
Class articleClass = a1.getClass();
Field field = articleClass.getField("s_top");
field.set(a1, 1);
```

It'll work, but it may be slow and it's an atypical approach to this problem.

Alternately, you could store either a `Map<String>` or a `Map<String,Boolean>` inside of your `Article` class, and have a public function within `Article` called `putSection(String section)`, and as you iterate, you would put the various section strings (or string/value mappings) into the map for each `Article`.  So, instead of statically defining which sections may exist and giving each `Article` a yes or no, you'd allow the list of possible sections to be dynamic and based on your xml import.

Comment: Your second description does not exactly follow my project (I have a specific set of "sections" and need to store which section(s) each article belongs to in a database.  BUT - your answer of 1) it's a pain to do it that way and 2) make a function in the Article model - that works - thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Java variables are not "dynamic", unlink actionscript for exemple. You cannot call or assign a variable without knowing it at compile time (well, with reflection you could but it's far to complex)

So yes, the solution is to have a switch case (only possible on strings with java 1.7), or using an hashmap or equivalent

Or, if it's about importing XML, maybe you should take a look on [JAXB](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/)

Comment: Up-voted as being helpful.  Other answer got the checkmark due to alternate solution offered.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get an attribute from an object, you need to make sure that you have "getters" and "setters" in your object. You also have to make sure you define `Section` in your article class.

Something like:

```
class Article{
  String section;   

  //constructor
  public Article(){
  };

  //set section
  public void setSection(Section section){
  this.section = section;
}
  //get section
  public String getSection(){
  return this.section; 

}
```